# Can you find the connection between these four images?

Tags: knowledge, visual, connections-puzzle

What's the connection between these images?

[image]

Comment: Is this an original puzzle?

Comment: No, it's not. My friend sent me this.

Comment: Did they provide any context? That might help solvers.

Comment: I'm afraid, not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The connection between the images is:

> **SCOTTY**

As the four images represent:

> **Top-left:** ["Scotty" the T. Rex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T.rex_Discovery_Centre), an exhibit at the T.rex Discovery Centre in Saskatchewan, Canada.
>
>  **Top-right:** [Scotty Moore](https://www.itv.com/news/2016-06-29/elvis-presleys-first-guitarist-scotty-moore-dies), Elvis Presley's first guitarist.
>
>  **Bottom-right:** The character [Montgomery "Scotty" Scott](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scotty_(Star_Trek)) from *Star Trek*.
>
>  **Bottom-left:** A [Scottish Terrier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scottish_Terrier), affectionately shortened to 'Scottie'.